# How to map Authors from svn to git?

Tags: git, github, svn

I have migrated svn repo project to git repo project. I was missed to add authors. Now in GitHub not showing contribution list. How to map svn authors to git after migration is completed?

Comment: This will require a "rebase" to rewrite the commit history with the correct authors.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to change the author and committer name and e-mail of multiple commits in Git?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/750172/how-to-change-the-author-and-committer-name-and-e-mail-of-multiple-commits-in-gi)